# Cosmos query to get the items inside list

Tags: azure, linq-to-entities, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a data structure like this:

```
{
  "commonId":"123",
  "Answers": [
    {
        "QuestionType": "1",
        "Answer": [
            "answer1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "QuestionType": "1",
        "Answer": [
            "answer2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "QuestionType": "2",
        "Answer": [
            "answer14"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

another file

```
 {
  "commonId":"123",
  "Answers": [
    {
        "QuestionType": "1",
        "Answer": [
            "answer3."
        ]
    },
    {
        "QuestionType": "1",
        "Answer": [
            "answer4."
        ]
    },
    {
        "QuestionType": "3",
        "Answer": [
            "answer24."
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here i want to fetch only the Answer of QuestionType=1 with commonId:123 into a list of string. I tried below code but it is not working

```
string sqlQueryText = "SELECT c.Answers.Answer FROM c WHERE c.commonId=123 AND c.Answers.QuestionType=1";
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
FeedIterator<List<string>> queryResultSetIterator = cosmosContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<List<string>>(queryDefinition);
FeedResponse<List<string>> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
```

I am new to this azure-cosmosdb and currently i am fetching all answers of all question types and using linq i am filtering particular question answers.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Joins.
Your query will look like this.

```
SELECT t.Answer
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.Answers
WHERE t.QuestionType = "1" AND c.commonId = 123
```

Response is below.

```
[
    {
        "Answer": [
            "answer1."
        ]
    },
    {
        "Answer": [
            "answer2."
        ]
    },
    {
        "Answer": [
            "answer3."
        ]
    },
    {
        "Answer": [
            "answer4."
        ]
    }
]
```

You can have a look at this very good blog regarding iterating through arrays in Cosmos [LINK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/understanding-how-to-query-arrays-in-azure-cosmos-db/).

Comment: i am getting null in "Answer"

Comment: Are your documents correct? You have an extra comma after "answer25." and "answer15." and the commonId is without quotes. And I'm assuming you actually have documents for the query. Can you update the question with your correct documents.

Comment: I updated the question but i cant upload my actual data here, thats why just changed the text, structure is same.

Comment: What is the value of commonId? Is it numeric 123 or a string "123" ? These 2 are different. If it is numeric the query will have c.commonId = 123 else it will be c.commonId = "123".

Comment: i given  c.commonId = "123" as string only

Comment: But what is in your document? Is it "commonId":"123" or "commonId":123 ? In your question you have mentioned commonId:"123" which is not a valid JSON attribute.

Comment: it was a mystake, actual one is "commonId":"123". In my actual json also its the same